# Swift CollectionView get first cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying on my viewDidLoad() to fetch images from my DB and then present the images, and highlight the first one.

My code thus far is:

```
                profile?.fetchImages(onComplete: { (errors, images) in
                    for error in errors {
                        print("Error", error)
                    }
                    for imageMap in images {
                        self.photos.append(imageMap.value)
                    }
                    if self.photos.count < self.MAX_PHOTOS {
                        self.photos.append(self.EMPTY_IMAGE)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                    self.updateSlideshowImages()
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                    let cell = self.photoCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
                    if cell != nil {
                        self.setBorder(cell!)
                    }
                })
```

However, for me cell is always nil, despite images existing and being fetched, and thus the setBorder is never called. Why is the cell always nil? I just want to set the border on the first cell.

Comment: call your setBorder function in cellForItemAt function instead. you can check for indexPath.row == 0 there.

Comment: what are you doing in self.updateSlideshowImages()

Comment: I think you can get the cell if you call you self.photoCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) inside  DispatchQueue.main.async {} only if there exists cells in collectionView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed `self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()` in async block so the `let cell = self.photoCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)` will run immediately before collection view reload, thats the reason you are getting `nil` for first cell.

You need to make sure that after collection view reload, I mean when all collection view cells are loaded then you can get and do your operations.

Alternatively, you can do this in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` like below...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier.jobCollectionViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! <#Your UICollectionViewCell#>

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
          //highlight cell here
      }

    return cell
}
```

And if you want to highlight cell after all images load in collection view then you need to check for datasource of collection view.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     let cell = ...

     if indexPath.row == arrImages.count-1 {

          let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
          if let cellImg = self.photoCollectionView.cellForItem(at: newIndexPath) {
              self.setBorder(cellImg)
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of highlighting the `UICollectionViewCell` in `viewDidLoad()` after receiving the response, highlight it in `willDisplay` `delegate` method, i.e.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        cell.isHighlighted = true
    }
}
```

And add border of cell in the **`isHighlighted`** property of `UICollectionViewCell` according to the cell highlight status, i.e.

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    override var isHighlighted: Bool{
        didSet{
            self.layer.borderWidth = self.isHighlighted ? 2.0 : 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

You can use **`isSelected`** property the same way in case you want to change appearance of the cell based on the selection status.

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set your cell's border in `cellForRow` method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
         self.setBorder(cell)
    }

    return cell
}
```